# PHP Counter not working, can't update MySQL Database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, database

I'm editing some PHP/Javascript codes that control a MySQL Database, and there is an issue where I cannot update old database entries. There are two php files--update.php and success.php.

In the update.php, there is a counter, $c, that is a variable for the rows in order to tell them apart. In success.php, it takes, I presume, the number that $c is (named 'count'), and results into the value for $i. The code is below--

Update.php:

```
<?php
$c = 0;

while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{

    echo"<tr>";
    echo "<td><div class='required'><input type=\"text\" name=\"".$c."ID\" onchange=\"turnWhite(this)\" size=\"7\" value= \"" .$row[3]."\"></div></td>";
    echo "<td><select name='".$c."Dataset1' onchange=\"return CheckData(".$c.")\">
    <option value='".$row[0]."'>".$row[0]."</option>";

$result1=mysql_query('SELECT Data FROM Database.Table2 ORDER BY Data');

while ($row1=mysql_fetch_row($result1))
{
   echo '<option>' . $row[0]. '</option>';
}
echo "</select></td>";
echo "<td><select name='".$c."Dataset2' onchange=\"return CheckData(".$c."\">
<option value='".$row[1]."'>".$row[1]."</option>";


$result=mysql_query('SELECT Data FROM Database.Table2 ORDER BY Data');
while ($row1=mysql_fetch_row($result1))
{
   echo '<option>' . $row[0]. '</option>';
}

echo "<td><input type=\"text\" id=\"".$c."Dataset_column2\" name=\"".$c."Dataset_column1\" size=\"30\" value= \"" .$row[2]."\"></td>;
echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"".$c."Dataset_column3\" size=\"30\" value= \"" .$row[3]."\"></td>;
echo "<td><div id='centerbutton'><input type='button' value='Update' onclick='validate(".$c."); return false;' /></div></td>";

$rows = "where 1=1 and `COLUMN2` ='" .$row[2]."' and `COLUMN3` ='".$row[3]."'";

echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"where".$c."\" value=\"".$rows."\">";
$c++;
```

Success.php:

```
$previous_URL = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$empty = "";

if(strpos($previous_URL,'update.php') !== false)
 {
   $i = $_GET['count'];
    if ($_FILES[$i."file"]["error"] > 0)
      {
       }
      else
        {
        }

      if (file_exists("C:/Web_content/Upload/" . $_FILES[$i."file"]["name"]))
           {
           echo "A file of this name already exists. 
Please rename your file and upload it again.";
           }
           if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET `COLUMN2` = ?, 
`COLUMN3` = ? ". $_POST['where'.$i] ))
```

I left some extra code out. My question is, what is it echoing, and how exactly does the $c counter work in update.php. And also in the success.php, what is the $i variable resulting into when it $_GET['count']. I keep getting the error code "A file of this name already exists.

Please rename your file and upload it again" but I'm not even uploading a file (in another column that I left out). Is it a problem in the update or success page? Why isn't up letting me update old database entries in MySQL through these codes?

Also, on a separate issue (but same php codes), sometimes when I try to update my new data, it would give me an error code saying that "A file exists" but under that it'd say "Notice: Undefined index: where170 in C:\Web_content\success.php" on the line where $_POST['where'.$i] is.

And then all my data would turn into NULL (so everything would be gone. But I backed my data up so I simply just import back my data when this happens).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `FROM Database.Table2` you're using a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html - use backticks `\`` to wrap it with.

Comment: Plus, you seem to be mixing MySQL APIs in two different bodies of code.

Comment: The Database and Table words are just replaced words for my actual database/table names. This code worked before, I'm not sure why it isn't working now..

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thank you. I switched all my mysql codes to mysqli, but my problem still persists